# wrapper script: fork: retry: No child processes

Tags: shell-script, path, fork

"myapplication" needs some setup or clean up done, so I use the following wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Do important set up stuff"
myapplication
echo "Clean up"
```

and put it in my path, named "myapplication" so it takes precedence over the original one automatically. This worked while testing but stopped once I actually put it into my path, giving the following error instead:

```
/home/user/bin/myapplication: fork: retry: No child processes
[more of the same line]
/home/user/bin/myapplication: fork: retry: No child processes
/home/user/bin/myapplication: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

and also causing other programs to malfunction with the same error in the time after the script was launched before it aborts with the last error.

Comment: What is the output of `ulimit`? What is the output of `cat /proc/meminfo`? (add to question)

Comment: Exporting a variable makes it an environment variable. Environment variables only affect child processes. Assigning the variables on the same line as starting an executable does the same, only syntax is different (looks different).

Comment: Sorry to mess you about I meant `ulimit -a` (specifically look at the `-u` entry)

Comment: @richard I just found the answer myself, sorry to have bothered you at all. Should this question+answer be deleted?

Comment: Could you edit it, to make it more general (remove references to steam). Then you could except your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the script is in the path, the line in the script which is supposed to call the original program instead calls the script, which creates infinite non terminating recursion until some system limit is reached.

The correct approach is to do `which myapplication` before putting the script in PATH to find the absolute path to the myapplication original executable and then use that path to call myapplication from the script.

The lesson to be learned in general is: this error may indicate a non terminating recursion.